# Excel 2007 Images Embedded In Comments = File Too Large

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, images, microsoft-office

I made a list of all the major electronics (pc towers, laptops, monitors, etc) at my workplace for inventory. To make it better I wanted to add pictures so I could see what each of the items looked like and a relative location (based on the pic). I did this by adding the pictures inside of comments. As I was going along I realized the file was growing substantially; which normally wouldn't be a problem. My problem was that it grew so large (~500MB I think) it had to 'repair' upon opening every time. When it did this it removed my comments (which included images as well) and I was essentially out of luck at this point.

I removed all the images so I could work on the inventory without any issues, but I really want images on there in some fashion. So my question...how can I achieve this and make it functional? Thanks.

Comment: How big are these images when you view the properties in your (Windows?) explorer?

Comment: Roughly ~2MB/each

Comment: tried to convert them to jpeg, if they are not on that format already? that would slice a big chunk out of the size.

Comment: Yes they are jpegs taken from my phone of the equipment around the office.

Comment: Do the images *have* to be inline? Can't you simply hyperlink to them instead?

Comment: I'd rather it be quick - hover over - boom there's a picture.

Answer (score 0):

First solution you should try:

- Edit all those pictures down to a very small size - you don't need detailed, high resolution images for this do you?

So take them down to a couple of kb each by resizing and saving as lower quality.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is 2MB for a picture is too high, so you should compress them down. My favorite program for this is [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/), but I believe there may be some command line utilities out there which are more suited for doing this in batches.

My second thought is, why Excel? You can [store images in an Access database](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/store-images-in-a-database-HP005280225.aspx) easily enough, and this kind of job feels like something you would use a database for (though I admittedly don't know the scope of the project). Converting this into a large scale database (not necessarily Access) might be your best option going forward.